# How can I cut a video after audio ends in moviepy?

Tags: python, audio, moviepy

Me and my friend are working on this project, and in the project he has to record a bunch of videos of him saying different words, for example he has to record a video of him saying the word "toast" and a different video of him saying the word "egg" (examples) etc.

I wanted to ask if there's a way to isolate the part where he says the word (both audio and video), because when he records the videos, there's gonna be a part with no audio both before and after he says the word. I wanted to see if there's a way to maybe take out those parts from the video (maybe leave like half a second of quietness just so the audio doesn't get cut in a weird spot) and only leave the part where he says the word.

I'm using python's MoviePy library but I don't mind trying to use other libraries. I'm open to any suggestions that may solve my issue because I've tried looking for a solution by myself and didn't really get anywhere. Let me know if there's any information missing in my post as I tried explaining my situation the best I could, thanks!

Comment: You could try this script : https://gist.github.com/vivekhaldar/595af6c6aa06ed061f6f3f6c97d087c3